# Can I ask the following question on Stack Overflow, or would it become off-topic?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

Question:  **Quality sources to self-teach programming skills (Python & C++ only)**

Details/Description:
In terms of courses ,which interactive/books sources would enable me to become a skillful and capable Bioinformatician/Programmer (my options are also open towards Gaming Industry Programmer). I have heard of Codecademy, Udacity, Udemy, Khan etc., but I need some help in deciding which ones are fairly well updated and are more known/popular today?

Also, is there a functional App that enables Python/C++ programming on Android KitKat/L Phones? My schedule and location are such that using a computer is often not possible so it would be nice to be able to implement and test simple code on my phone.

MY BACKGROUND : B.Tech Bioinformatics (computational biology) so I do know some basics of programming, and have some very basic level coding skills and some background in computer science as a part of my degree.

Comment: Those would be considered off-topic. (opinion-based)

Comment: ok Thanks for the clarifications. In that case is there any StackEx. site where this would be in the topic and not off the topic, because i believe this specific context, would somehow not really be so much opinion based but more of a logical guidance based, especially to a person who feels like a victim of "plethora of choices" lolz. I come to SE based on my experience and my gr8 feedback about it and hence choose to not rely much on other sites or blogs who give a discussion/rating on the same.

Answer (score -2):

Off-topic. You are asking for recommendations. Recommendations are inherently opinion-based, and as such not a good fit for the site. Also, your question contains multiple sub-questions, which is also somewhat of a no-no.

It *might* be acceptable on the programmers SE, but that only goes for the course recommendation portion.

Comment: PHEWWWWW!!!......thnx very much, finally someone gave me a specific guidance in the first response.....really it makes a lot of difference. Ok so how wud you suggest i put my question on Programmers SE so that i get atleast some legible rating because whatever answers i get will be pragmatic and mostly genuine, AND, i somehow need to finalize or narrow down my options to 2 or 3 sources thats all otherwise i constantly would have this fear/feeling of not being up with the latest/updated courses or techniques. ---"Just need some grid to start walking."

Comment: It's not acceptable on programmers.SE. @CodeMan

Comment: @eddie_cat how about now i changed it lot more

Comment: i am afraid now whether my own question would become into an answer  as i go on re-editing more and more.........

Comment: @CodeMan see here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Note that recommendation questions are specifically off-topic there as well. Opinion-based questions like this are not really appropriate *anywhere* on Stack Exchange. For this sort of thing I'd recommend browsing reddit on r/learnprogramming.

Comment: @eddie_cat yes i get it...thnx

Answer (score -6):

I now feel tempted to actually answer your questions' content, but I won't **:-)** because that would be off-topic as well, like your questions.

Idea: do not ask for 'quality' but ask for more examples on ***where*** exactly you might find a starting point course, without asking for the 'best' one.

Comment: lolz, i really appreciate the concern, thanks a lot, i will try and figure out how i can reword so that i can bring this on the topic........what about the place to post this, lets assume that i reword my question properly then on which SE should i be posting this question?........it seems u have gone through my kind of situation before...thnx

Comment: Even your suggested modification would be off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Asking for the "best" is opinion based and a recommenddation question.  Drop the "best" and ask "where" you still have a recommendation question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 how about now...........i dropped more than best i even dropped recommendation. Now it is just a finite mining and review like question and not even exactly a review question any more.

Comment: @CodeMan the issue is you are asking for sources and/or resources.  It's not strictly the recommendation part that makes it off-topic.  These types of questions, while were allowed in the very beginning of Stack Overflow, have been off-topic for a long time because regardless of your intent, they become a magnet for spam, terrible answers like "`Foo is the best, use it`", end up being a popularity contests, and get out dated very very quickly.  I doubt there is a way you can make it on-topic for any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @CodeMan Your best options are getting a little more rep and going into [chat] or asking it on one of the many forums on the internet that will accept these types of questions.

Comment: @psubsee2003 i understand......well thnx for the responses.....got some usefull insights